# Creating keycloak custom theme

Tags: freemarker, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have in my UI three views:

- starting page (with links to registration and login pages)
- login page
- registration page

I don't know how to display firstly the starting page. My starting page in my custom theme is the login page (my-site/auth). How to change this?

I tried with request parameters, by I can't get the url params in .ftl template pages.

How to extend the server by endpoint or read url param in template?

Maybe there is another solution... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use my own server to show the starting page, instead of involving keycloak in all of this. Example:

- Starting page at -> *web.myapp.company.com*
- Keycloak at -> *auth.myapp.company.com*
- Application at -> *myapp.company.com*

In *web.myapp.company.com* you would have an standard web page, with a link to *myapp.company.com* to access the application (which will redirect you to keycloak authentication if not logged in) and another link to *auth.myapp.company.com/realms/myrealm/protocols/open-id-connect/registrations* in case the user wants [to register himself](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Direct-link-to-register-page-td629.html).